# Strange java.beans.Introspector behavior on WebLogic with DCEVM and HotSwapAgent

Tags: weblogic, hotswap, dcevm

I am running WebLogic on JVM 1.7 with DCEVM (full implementation) and HotSwapAgent with custom plugin that gets triggered on every onClassLoad.

I run into problems with Freemarker, which uses java.beans.Introspector. What I discovered is the fact that when I call Introspector.flushCaches on the method called by HotSwapAgent (through ReflectionCommand), then the BeanInfo in Introspector is invalidated properly (checked with debugger in that thread). However when I make request to the WLS appserver, then Introspector for the worker thread shows the old values!

This seems like some thread-local implementation, but I was not able to find anything that would point to that assumption in java.beans.Introspector's documentation.

Does anybody have any clue why this is happening and how to resolve that?

Currently I store the information about reloaded classes in separate class and reload everything that's in that cache from the request thread, which works.

Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this thanks to @ddekany and his answer to related problem at [Freemarker removeIntrospectionInfo does not work with DCEVM after model hotswap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721199/freemarker-removeintrospectioninfo-does-not-work-with-dcevm-after-model-hotswap)

It seems that JVM (at least HotSpot 1.7) caches Introspector's cache per ThreadGroup. This means, that `Introspector.flushCaches` must be called in a thread that runs in corresponding `ThreadGroup`.

When I executed this for all the ThreadGroups in the application then everything started working again properly.

I wasn't able to find any documentation why the `java.beans.Introspector` is cached per `ThreadGroup` so if anybody has an reliable information to this, please add a comment with link.

Thanks.

Update:

Comming from JDK7 source

```
/**
     * Introspect on a Java Bean and learn about all its properties, exposed
     * methods, and events.
     * <p>
     * If the BeanInfo class for a Java Bean has been previously Introspected
     * then the BeanInfo class is retrieved from the BeanInfo cache.
     *
     * @param beanClass  The bean class to be analyzed.
     * @return  A BeanInfo object describing the target bean.
     * @exception IntrospectionException if an exception occurs during
     *              introspection.
     * @see #flushCaches
     * @see #flushFromCaches
     */
    public static BeanInfo getBeanInfo(Class<?> beanClass)
        throws IntrospectionException
    {
        if (!ReflectUtil.isPackageAccessible(beanClass)) {
            return (new Introspector(beanClass, null, USE_ALL_BEANINFO)).getBeanInfo();
        }
        ThreadGroupContext context = ThreadGroupContext.getContext();
        BeanInfo beanInfo;
        synchronized (declaredMethodCache) {
            beanInfo = context.getBeanInfo(beanClass);
        }
        if (beanInfo == null) {
            beanInfo = new Introspector(beanClass, null, USE_ALL_BEANINFO).getBeanInfo();
            synchronized (declaredMethodCache) {
                context.putBeanInfo(beanClass, beanInfo);
            }
        }
        return beanInfo;
    }
```

This has been definitely added in JDK7, because I checked JDK6 code and it's not there!.

Comment: It would be nice if this functionality was embedded into HotSwapAgent as a plugin. I will take a look into that.